# Trigger an event after delay

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table "TClaim" in SQL Server with the following structure:

```
idclaim, date_claim, state,
```

example:

```
1 | 12/22/2013 | declared
```

I want to set up an event that fires after the expiration of a delay of 15 days from the date of claim without processing the claim by a user (value of the "state" column changes to "treated" if it is treated).

the event is to change the value of the "state" column in "critical" for example.

What can you suggest?

thank you

Comment: `What can you suggest?` a cronjob / scheduled event

Answer (score 0):

Set up a job in SQL Server Agent (see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx)).

Such a job would run every day at a specific time.  It would look at the records that are exactly 15 days old and do the processing that you want to do.  It should take care of properly logging its actions, so you can report on the results.  Often, such a job generates a report that is emailed or available through an online tool.

Comment: You are right but the problem is SQL Agent is not included in sql express edition, what about the trigger and WAITFOR function ?

Comment: If you have a real application running in SQL Server, then just upgrade to the full featured version.  It is not very expensive.